# How to change the font-style of a Bootstrap form input with Custom Font

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-4

I am building a website using Bootstrap framework (Bootstrap 4). I have included a custom font (GeosansLight) throughout the website using the body's CSS attribute. The custom font is making the default bootstrap form inputs appear too light to be noticed.

On a particular page, I tried to add a bootstrap form using the bootstrap template, along with the placeholders for each field, but the format of the input is too light to be read. I tried changing the font to the default font and the form elements become dark again. Along with that, I also tried making the letters bold using font-style: bold attribute but nothing happens to the form elements, just the form labels.

HTML:

```
<form>
    <div class="row mt-2">
      <label for="inputName" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Full Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Enter your full name">
      </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">


input {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 17px;
}

label {
  text-align: center;
}

form {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 15px;

}

body {
font-family: GeosansLight;

}

@font-face { font-family: GeosansLight; src: url('GeosansLight.ttf');  }

form input {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}
</style>
```

I expected a normal Bootstrap form input field dark enough for everyone to see but the output was a very light, faded form input with a placeholder. When we type anything in the placeholder, the resulting text is light as well.
What attributes do I need to add to darken the form-input so that it is not influenced by the custom font?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding then few fonts as Light, bold, normal and use font with different font-weight.
Some good stuff is also
[here](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/02/setting-weights-and-styles-at-font-face-declaration/)

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'Ubuntu';
      src: url('Ubuntu-RI-webfont.eot');
      src: url('Ubuntu-RI-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
           url('Ubuntu-RI-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
           url('Ubuntu-RI-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
           url('Ubuntu-RI-webfont.svg#UbuntuItalic') format('svg');
   font-weight: 400;
   font-style: italic;
}

@font-face {
   font-family: 'Ubuntu';
      src: url('Ubuntu-B-webfont.eot');
      src: url('Ubuntu-B-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
           url('Ubuntu-B-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
           url('Ubuntu-B-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
           url('Ubuntu-B-webfont.svg#UbuntuBold') format('svg');
   font-weight: 700;
   font-style: normal;
}
```

And html would be

```
.u400 {
   font-family: 'Ubuntu', arial, sans-serif;
   font-weight: 400;
   font-style: normal;
}

.u400i {
   font-family: 'Ubuntu', arial, sans-serif;
   font-weight: 400;
   font-style: italic;
}

.u700 {
   font-family: 'Ubuntu', arial, sans-serif;
   font-weight: 700;
   font-style: normal;
}

.u700i {
   font-family: 'Ubuntu', arial, sans-serif;
   font-weight: 700;
   font-style: italic;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are importing the Geosans**Light** font. Try to find the same font but normal or bold to solve your issue

Comment: I tried a different font, it seems to display the forms normally now, but I wanted to preserve the same font throughout the website whilst making the form elements bold enough to be visible, is there a way to do that?